# Using 8gb 2RX4 PC3- 10600R 1333MHZ DDR3 on DL380e Gen8 Server?

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant, hpe

we are planning for a memory upgrade of our hp ProLiant 380e gen8 server.i've found a refurbish memory on amazon, since we have a limited budget we opted out to buy a refurbish units instead of a new one. we found a seller on Amazon that offers an HP 16GB(2x8gb) kit 2rx4 pc3 10600R 1333MHZ ddr3 SDRAM Memory for $37.18 per kit that is pulled out from dl380 gen 6 servers. is it compatible with our gen8 server? since our server has an existing ram that is PC3-L (low-voltage), does the gen 8 server has backward compatibility on PC3 (standard voltage) Ram? can anyone here confirm that this memory kit is compatible with our gen8 server? thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use refurbished memory on your HP Gen8 server with some limitations. You can't use PC3L (low voltage) and PC3 on a one memory cannel.

Another way to decide the problem is using PC3L on CPU1 and PC3 on CPU2.

Read HP Gen8 server installation guide.